# Modified Korteweg-de Vries equation and curvature

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

I have issues with an exercise regarding the modified Korteweg-de Vries flow.

[image]

[image]

My problem is with c).

c) Assuming that the curve is arc length parametrized the bending energy is given by

$$
B(\gamma)=\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^L \langle T',T' \rangle ds
$$

One can show that

$$
B(\gamma)=\frac{1}{2} E(\gamma). 
$$

To show the claim we must show $\dot{E(\gamma_t)}=0$. We have

\begin{align*}
\dot{E(\gamma_t)}=\int_{0}^L \dot{(\kappa^2 ds)}
=\int_{0}^L \dot{(\kappa^2 ds)}
=\int_{0}^L 2 \kappa \dot{\kappa} ds+\kappa^2 \dot{ds}.
\end{align*}

In particular we have

$$
\dot{ds}
=\langle \dot{(\gamma)}', T \rangle ds            \\
=\langle (\frac{1}{2}\kappa^2 T-\kappa' N)', T \rangle ds \\
=\langle ( \frac{1}{2} (2 \kappa \kappa' T+\kappa^2 T')-\kappa'' N-\kappa' N'), T \rangle ds.
$$

Using this and the result from b) and $N=-JT$ we get

$$
\dot{E(\gamma_t)}=\int_{0}^L \kappa \kappa''' ds+2 \int_{0}^L \kappa^3 \kappa'ds
$$

However, I do not see why this expression vanishes. I have tried integration by parts in order to exploit the fact that the curves are closed (and therefore have the same curvature at the beginning and the endpoint) but this has not yielded the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of those terms are exact derivatives so if the solution is $L$-periodic then they integrate to zero.

$\kappa \kappa''' = \frac{d}{ds}\left(\kappa \kappa'' -\frac12 (\kappa')^2 \right)$

$\kappa^3 \kappa' = \frac{d}{ds}\left( \frac{\kappa^4}{4}\right)$